# hiding a menu while loading

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is i need to hide a menu in my web page while the page is loading i.e, in my page there r so many urls,while navigating from one url to another url i want to hide the menu while loading icon is displaying in the page and should be displayed after loading icon disappeared.

I have already tried with this

```
frame.contentWindow.document.addEventListener("load",hideTeamReviewMenu(),false);
    window.onbeforeunload=function hideTeamReviewMenu() {    

    if (document.getElementById('teamReviewMenuId') != null) {
        if ($(headerMenuList).find('#teamReviewMenuId')[0] != null) {
            $(headerMenuList).find('#teamReviewMenuId')[0].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the parenthesis from `hideTeamReviewMenu()` in the `frame.contentWindow.document.addEventListener` line

Comment: will this help u? https://jsfiddle.net/05r8bb89/3/

Comment: no it is throwing an error hideTeamReviewMenu is not defined